# Using SOAP with php , utilising nusoap library

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

Hi i tried to run the code of a tutorial but i am getting an error.
The soap server code is the following.

```
<?php
function getStockQuote($symbol) {

return "Hi jerkwad ".$symbol;
}

require('lib/nusoap.php');

$server = new soap_server();

$server->configureWSDL('StockServer', 'urn:stockquote');

$server->register("getStockQuote",
                array('symbol' => 'xsd:string'),
                array('return' => 'xsd:string'),
                'urn:stockquote',
                'urn:stockquote#getStockQuote');

$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)
                      ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
?>
```

The Soap client is this.

```
<?php
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

$c = new soapclient('http://localhost/stockserver.php');

$stockprice = $c->call('getStockQuote',
              array('symbol' => 'ABC'));

echo "The stock price for 'ABC' is $stockprice.";

?>
```

and this is the error i get.

Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient(http://localhost/stockserver.php) [soapclient.soapclient]: failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\wamp\www\SoapClient.php on line 4

Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient() [soapclient.soapclient]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://localhost/stockserver.php" in C:\wamp\www\SoapClient.php on line 4

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\SoapClient.php on line 13

I am sure i am doing something stupid, i am a total soap noob.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working just fine on my own server. It is not nusoap related, since NuSOAP claims to have no extensions requirements.

You should check basic configuration points :

- is the http://localhost/stockserver.php really available (open it in a browser)
- can you ping "localhost" ? (i know it seems stupid, but [it did occur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890663/cannot-resolve-localhost))
- ultimately, try and replace `localhost` by `127.0.0.1`

Comment: localhost is online and the stockserver.php responds when hit
i have no idea whats wrong